# Creating my Stripe account as a customer for other Stripe users

Tags: stripe-payments

During Stripe OAuth, I'm trying to create myself as a customer for my users such that I can pay them with my *own* credit card.

I've gotten 2 error messages when using [Stripe's CreateCustomer API call](https://stripe.com/docs/api#customers):

When manually entering my card info as a "dictionary" (in PHP, i.e., array).

```
OAuth based requests must use card tokens from Stripe.js, but card details were directly provided.
```

When [generating a card token](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_card_token) first and feeding that instead into `CreateCustomer()`

```
Your card was declined.
```

Is creating myself as a customer for other Stripe users not possible?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? We just ran into that ourselves.

Comment: @Citizen  If I can recall, I think the issue is that to do this one uses their own keys and then the user's keys in this process. I don't quite remember what I ended up doing, but I usually post an answer if I figure something out, so I don't think its possible (moreover, Stripe is a top-notch company so I doubt it's their mistake).